# Rails sending multiple params through dropdown box

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two dropdown boxes. One is for campaign size(small, medium, large) and the other one is for the theme selection.

I want to be able to send params dynamically through onchange event handler

current code looks like this

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-padding-helper">
  <%= form_tag product_builder_path, method: :get do %>
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-padding-helper">
    <%= label_tag 'Campaign Size' %></br>
    <%= select_tag 'type', options_for_select(['Small (4 Products)', 'Medium (7 Products)', 'Large (10 Products)' ]), multiple: false, :include_blank => true, class: "form-control",  data: { remote: true }, onchange: "this.form.submit();"  %>
   </div>
<% end %>

 <%= form_tag(product_builder_path, method: :get, remote: true) do %>
   <div class="col-lg-7 col-padding-helper">
     <%= label_tag 'Theme' %></br>
     <%= select_tag 'theme', options_for_select(['Default BWX Theme', 'Black Friday Theme']), multiple: false, :include_blank => true, class: "form-control", onchange: "this.form.submit();" %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
    </div>
```

The workflow that I am thinking in my head is that once user selects the campaign size it will submit a form through ajax and have something like this as a url. which then I can display display right type of html template on the webpage.

```
/product_builder?type=small
```

and after when they select the theme is it possible to do something like this? and this will change the theme of the type that I have chosen above

```
/product_builder?type=small&theme=black
```

so basically it's adding params to current URL

I don't even know if this is possible, any help or guidance would be awesome

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the current page html based on the selection of the first dropdown?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Can you sketch out a mock up of what you want to see on the page to walk us through it?

Comment: If you put both selects in the same form and make sure that the selects are preselected based on your params that should solve your problem as far as I understand your question.

Comment: @Beartech in this case two dropdowns, I have two different condition to meet. One is size and theme. User can choose between themes and size of  the campaigns.

for example

if I choose size 4 from the drop down(campaign size) it will display corresponding html and after when i choose the theme it will change the style of the campaign size that I have chosen. Does that make little bit more sense? thank you

Comment: @Albin I actually thought about that today. thank you

Comment: I guess it's still not clear to me. When a person chooses a size should the theme dropdown update to something different? Or is another part of the page changing when selections from the dropdowns are made? I also don't understand why there isn't just one form. Why not use a single `form_for`?

Comment: You could use a single `form_for` and have the first dropdown update the page and set it's value using AJAX. Same with the second dropdown. Those values will get submitted as params automatically.